# Update your target API level by August 31, 2023 to release updates to your app

Tags: android, flutter, deployment, google-play-services, google-play-console

I got a mail from the play store that Update your target API level by August 31, 2023 to release updates to your app.

That warning message looks like this,
[image]

I have updated my flutter code that targeted targetSdkVersion 33 and uploaded in play store after play store reviewed my app they approved my app update but this warning message still showing me.

My updated code for Android 13,
[image]

please help me to fix this problem!

Comment: Double-check your AndroidManifest.xml file to ensure that you have correctly set the targetSdkVersion to 33, and that there are no discrepancies in the file that could trigger the warning.

Comment: Please check for all the latest build versions in the Google Play Store you have uploaded to the different tracks (internal test etc.). In my case I had an old and forgotten internal test version that I have't updated since last year and that still had 30 as `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: @MohammedRampurawala  problem is solved!

Comment: what did you miss last time @DhruvMavani

Comment: @towhid I wait sometimes and the problem is resolved. I change nothing.

Comment: I got the same warning from Google Play but my app's targetSdkVersion is 31 and Google Play says that it isn't necessary if your targetSdkVersion is 31 or above. In this case, can I update in the future?

Answer (score 1):

First, I see one button in the warning message 'app bundle' after I uploaded my latest app bundle then also warning message note was removed but sometimes the play store removes the warning message automatically in this case!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I updated the SDK version from 31 to 33 in build.gradle.

```
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
```

Then compile a new bundle, using it to create releases listed in the View affected app bundle (including testing and production) to deactivate the old outdated bundle.